# What's the difference between [installing] and [setup]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installing) only has 112 questions. A quick look says the answer is *Nothing at all*, and it probably needs merging and synonymizing into the vastly more popular [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setup).

The trigger was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248408/using-license-file-in-sitecore-installing) which used both tags together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's a little more complicated than that.

I made them all synonyms of [installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation).